# Is it possible to set a version name of a file in a s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a current solution for my s3 bucket where I store exe files with specific versions like:

- s3://my-bucket

  - /latest

    - my-exe-v1.xxx3.exe
  - /history

    - my-exe-v1.xxx2.exe
    - my-exe-v1.xxx1.exe
    - ...

Is it possible for versionned bucket to set the version name ?
In my case it would allow to get the bucket like:

- s3://my-bucket

  - my-exe.exe -> contains versions (v1.xxx1,v1.xxx2,v1.xxx3, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 does not support naming a specific version. Instead it uses unique version IDs to differentiate among multiple versions of the same object. The main purpose of object versioning is to enable you to restore objects that are accidentally deleted or overwritten and compliance reasons.

Common practice to achieve what you want is to set versions as part of the objects' key, i.e., like a folder per version. For example,  you could decide to have `s3://my-bucket/V1/my-object` and so on.

Beat,
Stefan

Comment: In my case, I think there will be too much versionning (hence too much folders) to be efficient but I know for sure now that what I had in mind isn't possible, thanks!

Comment: In S3 the structure is completely flat i.e. there are no real folders. There are only keys and objects. For example, `s3://my-bucket/V1/my-object` is just a key name and nothing more. You can have an arbitrary number of such keys at no performance cost (at least regarding S3).